# How to align horizontally the label of TextField in React Material-UI at the center?

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I'd like to align horizontally the label at the center of this TextField:

```
import React from "react";
import { withStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import TextField from "@material-ui/core/TextField";       
        
        export default function BasicTextField() {
          return (
              <TextField
                id="standard-basic"
                label="Standard"/>
          );
        }
```

So far I was able to align the label at the right:

```
import React from "react";
import { withStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import TextField from "@material-ui/core/TextField";       

const StyledTextField = withStyles({
          root: {
            "& label": {
              transformOrigin: "top right",
                right: "0",
                left: "auto" 
            }
          }
        })(TextField);
        
        export default function BasicTextField() {
          return (
              <StyledTextField
                id="standard-basic"
                label="Standard"/>
          );
        }
```

Is there a way to align the label horizontally at the center?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
root: {
        "& label": {
          width: "100%",
          textAlign: "center",
          transformOrigin: "center",
            "&.Mui-focused": {
              transformOrigin: "center"
            }
         }
      }
```

Comment: @innoxius just edited answer, I think with correct variant

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Box component to center your label like this:

```
<Box display="flex" justifyContent="center">
    <StyledTextField id="standard-basic" label="Standard"/>
</Box>
```

Or a Grid component:

```
<Grid container
  direction="row"
  justify="center"
  alignItems="center"
>
  <StyledTextField id="standard-basic" label="Standard"/>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Thanks! That doesn't work as expected.  The field is centered but not the label.